# Passing $scope.master to next form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have an array in `$scope.master`, and I've tried passing this when the form has submitted in the following manner:

```
<form novalidate class="css-form" method='post' action='www.example.com'>
<INPUT type='hidden' name='yourData' value='$scope.master'> 
</form>
```

But the above seems to be passing the string "$scope.master".

I've also tried putting this in another javascript variable and passing the variable, but that doesn't seem to work either.

What would the best approach to this be?

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: I would suggest reading through the documentation on forms with angular first at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form and the use of ngValue at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

The former will be more important if you're trying to pass an Array to a hidden inputs value, specifically look at ngSubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{}}` to write into the view with Angular (also omit the `$scope` when writing into the view):

```
<INPUT type='hidden' name='yourData' value='{{master}}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ng-submit directive to your form.

```html
  <form novalidate ng-submit="SubmitForm()"
    <input type="hidden" name="yourData" ng-model="master"/>  
</form>
```

In your controller:

> $scope.SubmitForm = function(){   $http.post('/someUrl',
>   $scope.master);
>
> }